# Custom virtual path provider not called for extensionless paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I ensure that my custom virtual path provider is called even for paths that don't have an extension?

For example if I do this in my controller, my provider is not executed:

```
return View("Home");
```

But if I do this, it is called:

```
return View("Home.cshtml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a custom path engine and now everything seems to be working

```
>         private class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
>         {
>             private static string[] NewPartialViewFormats = new[] {
> "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
> 
>             public CustomViewEngine()
>             {
>                 base.PartialViewLocationFormats =
> base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(NewPartialViewFormats).ToArray();
>             }
>         }
```

In Application_Start:

```
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IIS are you using? Are you using a `VirtualPathProvider` or `MVC` routing?

You need to make sure you have a wildcard mapping in II6 or II7 with classic mode.

This [article](http://ruslany.net/2008/09/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/) should help show you how in different versions of IIS. Unless the request is routed through to ASP.NET your code won't get called, IIS will just return `404`.

In IIS7.5 you could try adding the following config. This is the equivalent of wildcard mapping and should be enabled by default in .NET 4.

```
<system.webServer>     
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">     
   </modules>     
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: VirtualPathProvider with iis 7.5 integrated pipeline.